# io_service::run() does not complete after migration to boost 1.72

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have an application doing a lot ow work in io_service::run(). Lots of client / server tcp communication, timers, post() calls, etc. I has been working fine with boost 1.66 / asio. After switching to boost 1.72 run() does not exit anymore after all work items are processed. As a workaround I maintain number of outstanding work items and setup a timer. Once that number reaches 0, the timer handler calls io_service::stop() to complete run(). Before switching to boost 1.72 it worked without this.

Is there a way to find out what causes run() method to hang. I wonder if someone knows about any changes  between boost 1.66 and 1.72 which could cause such behavior change.

I tried using BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING but it did not help. When all the work is done debug output generated by Handler Tracker stops and all items seem to be completed, while run() keeps hanging().

I can't reproduce this in a simple example of any reasonable size. Even with the application it sometimes it completes as expected. The application is single-threaded and calls run() in the main thread synchronously.

Comment: Do you have any work guards (`io_service::work`, `asio::make_work_guard` or `executor_work_guard<>`)? If so, that's the reason. If not, you _do_ have async operations pending. Your observations from handler tracking lead me to suspect the first reason.

Comment: @sehe Does not look like I have work guards. Another point is that If I had them, it would hang with boost 1.66 as well.

Comment: Hmm. Can you inspect the process in the stuck phase in a debugger and investigate the state? Perhaps you'll find interesting stuff like merely observing whether the problem also occurs when building without optimizations

Comment: Otherwise it might really be informative to reduce until you have a minimal reproducer. Invariably, this going to turn up the culprit sooner rather than later. And if not, you have a bug report.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to bisect the git commits to find when the behavior changed. This will only be viable if you can reliably reproduce the issue